# Selecting which button pressed in recyclerview row kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have had a look at various stackoverflow questions and answers to this problem and still struggling to get the right solution.  If someone has a link to my problem with a solution I will mark it as duplicate but I have not found one yet.

Note: Code has been upgraded to `Kotlin` so mindful of some code may not be optimized for Kotlin best practices yet.

I have captured the button pressed in my `RecyclerAdapter` and now want it passed back to my Activity that has the `recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener`.

My `RecyclerAdapter` code is as follows:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotesPicsRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val data_provider = arrayList[position]

    holder.notePicShareButton.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Share Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    holder.notePicChangePicButton.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Edit Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    holder.notePicDeleteButton.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Delete Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    try {
        holder.imageText.text = data_provider.notes_text
        val imageFile = data_provider.image_path
        val inputStream = context.assets.open(imageFile)
        val d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null)
        holder.imagePath.setImageDrawable(d)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

class RecyclerViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    internal var imagePath: ImageView
    internal var imageText: TextView
    internal var notePicShareButton: Button
    internal var notePicChangePicButton: Button
    internal var notePicDeleteButton: Button
    init {
        imagePath = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.single_note_pic_image) as ImageView
        imageText = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.single_note_pic_text) as TextView
        notePicShareButton = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.single_note_pic_share_button) as Button
        notePicChangePicButton = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.single_note_pic_change_pic_button) as Button
        notePicDeleteButton = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.single_note_pic_delete_button) as Button
    }
}
```

My onCreate in my Activity code snippet is as follows:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            MyRecyclerViewClickListener(this, object : MyRecyclerViewClickListener.OnItemClickListener {
                override fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {
                      val thePos = arrayList[position].list_id
                      Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "This row: $thePos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            })
    )
```

All `Toast` messages in my `RecyclerAdapter` and `Activity` work so I have captured which button is being pressed as well as the row being selected, but I need the button information to be passed back to my `Activity` so I can use it with the row that was pressed.  Not sure how to proceed and still digging but any info would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure about your problem but according to my understanding of your problem this will solve your problem you can use interfaces for the views as well as for item view which will pass the view and position and then you can get the id of the view in your activity using this interface

Comment: not clear what you are asking as you say `I have captured which button is being pressed as well as the row being selected` then again what you needed by saying this `the button information to be passed back to my Activity so I can use it with the row that was pressed` even you have `view` instance in every `listener `

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this.

Create Variable and setter of that variable in your `activity`.

```
private YourObject localVariable;

public YourObject setLocalVariable(YourObject localVariable){
   this.localVariable= localVariable;
}
```

And on Clicking on `recycle View` List `Listener`.

`Typecast` your `context` into your `activity` and set your Local variable over there.

```
((YourActivity)context).setLocalVariable(arrayList[position])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EventBus library it will achieve what you want easy

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus